# Linebreak in .php file before "<?php" destroys whole code on MAMP (Mac OS X)

Tags: php, macos

If I would sum the HR we needed to solve this problem, it would took us two days.
For some reason on my mac machine the code stop to work, while on windows machines everything runs perfect.

It was very hard to figure out was had gone wrong, because the error message does not gave us any clue and pointed us into several wrong directions like sending wrong http header and things like that.

Comment: Have you even tried to search SO for "headers already sent"? Aside a "cookie set" problem that's all about some invisible characters before `<?php`. And IMO any year+ experienced phpdev is aware of this behaviour, it's sure strange this issue took you 2 days to solve.

Comment: Out team is new to PHP.
We googled but did not find a result.

Comment: question named "headers already sent" is 4th on a [stackoverflow' PHP F.A.Q.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=faq&pagesize=15) and accepted answer covers exactly your case.

Comment: Your comments sounds very pompous to me but thank you anyway. Now I know exactly what it is.

Comment: Was not trying to offend you in any way, just wanted to be sure you have not missed that question on a F.A.Q., cuz it has very detailed answer, good to know

Comment: Thank you! I read it and find out a lot of things!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple and we just figured it out trough line by line compare of some files in the svn history.

A simple break of line before `"<?php>"` destroyed the whole system.
I really dont know how this is possible.
Normally the php parser should ignore this.

I had to listen to Mac bashing for two days from my colleagues, which really sucks...

Comment: I got a useful answer from PHPStorm
1. PhpStorm creates files in UTF-8 encoding without BOM
2. If such file was created elsewhere with BOM, then you can always use "File | Remove BOM" to remove it

Comment: On any environnment, having any caracters before <?php­­ will throw a fatal error.